# Export data back to existing csv file

Tags: excel, vba, export-to-csv

I have created an application already in excel where one sheet (Sheet 1) acts as a database that stores data for thousands of records.  Another sheet (Sheet 2) acts as a form where users selects a record > the form gets populated with data from Sheet 1 > user updates fields > and then save it back to Sheet 1.

This has been working great, except now we need to be able to have multiple users working in the same worksheet making updates at the same time.  I cannot use the Excel Share Workbook functionality because many parts of my VBA code require unprotecting and reprotecting certain sheets and that functionality doesn't work on shared workbooks.

So now, I have split the workbook into two separate workbooks.  Workbook 1 has the data in it and is saved as a .csv file.  Workbook 2 is just a form that has a connection to workbook 1 via the get External Data functionality already in Excel.  I can import data from the .csv file without a problem, but the only way I am finding to export the data back into the .csv file is through doing a save as.  This causes a problem because it turns my multi-sheet macro enabled workbook into a csv file after the save.

Is there any other way I can update the csv file without saving my workbook as a .csv?

I don't need any code done, I just need ideas more than anything.  This is already a fairly large application and due to security restrictions I have already been told I cannot use a SQL server connection and we do not have access to Access to use an Access database.  So solution has to stay inside excel/text files?

Comment: Classic way of doing this is via a lock file. When you are about to write to the workbook - create a small/zero-lengh file in the directory. Presence of that file means that you are writing to the database workbook. Once done - remove it. Only keep it up for when you're actually writing - keep that time as short as possible. Other workbooks should check that file before updating.

Comment: @LoganReed That is actually a really good suggestion.  That way two people aren't trying to save to the workbook at the same time.  However, I still have the problem of how do I write back to the .csv workbook without saving my current workbook as a .csv file???

Comment: You don't need the Access application to create/use an mdb database file:  http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=40365

Comment: There are two ways of doing that: 1) use `Workbooks.Open` to open another workbook, edit it and save; 2) don't use a workbook to open a .csv file. The format is simple enough to just handle it from VBA. The VBA [Open](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264163.aspx) statement also has different ways to lock the file you're working on, so you can actually guarantee only one worksheet will be writing to a file without an explicit lock file. But this approach requires a bit more careful coding (keeping in mind multiple worksheets running at the same time).